# How to execute cucumber typescript test in parallel on selenium nodes

Tags: typescript, cucumber, selenium-grid

I am trying to develop a testing framework to test my company's web application. I wanted to test a basic login scenario on multiple browsers during a single execution.
For this I already have a Selenium grid up and running. But I cannot figure out how to execute the same test on both nodes at the same time.
I need a test runner for my test framework. This is what my current framework set up is :

1. My tests are written in typescript
2. Tests written in gherkin syntax, so I have for my login scenario, a Login.feature file and the corresponding step definitions in Login.step file
3. Selenium grid with 2 nodes one each for Chrome and Firefox browsers.
4. Selenium grid is set up with docker compose. My grid is already up and running. I can see a node for Firefox and Chrome registered in this UR: http://localhost:4444/grid/console.
5. I do not want to use third party integrations like Lambatest or BrowserStack etc. yet. I would like to have a very minimal framework set up using open source libraries only first which I will then scale up.

I want to execute my Given, When and Then steps in Login.step file on both the nodes in my selenium grid. Currently my code is only able to instantiate only one driver at a time. And hence my test only runs in either one of the nodes at any given time.
I know that if my tests were written in Java I could use TestNG.xml file to direct my tests to both nodes. But what is the equivalent of that for JavaScript or typescript tests?
I read that Jest has a test runner library but cannot find any Github repos or documentation on how to use it for parallel execution of my tests on Selenium nodes. I have tried to integrate Jest solely to have access to its test runner framework but couldn't figure out how to do it..
This is my Login.feature file:

```
Feature: Login to the NUC website using login credentials with various roles

  @Login
  Scenario Outline: User with various or no access rights visits XXX webpage
    Given user has "<role>" access rights
    When User visits the XYZ website
    When User inputs the username "<uname>" and password "<pass>"
    Then User should see the login page with the  title containing the word "<title>"
    Examples:
      | uname                   | pass            | role               | title     |
      | xxxx@zzzz               | xxxxxxxxxx      | admin              | DASHBOARD |
      | yyyy@fm                 | xxxxxxxxxx      | manager            | Invalid   |
```

This is my Login.step file:

```
import { Given, Then, When, DataTable } from '@cucumber/cucumber';
import { By, WebElement, until } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { CreateChromeDriverInstance } from "c:/Selenium_test_framework/step_definitions/Driver_Instance";
import { CreateFirefoxDriverInstance } from "c:/Selenium_test_framework/step_definitions/Driver_Instance";
import assert from 'assert/strict';
import { then } from 'cucumber-tsflow/dist';
import { defineFeature, loadFeature } from 'jest-cucumber';


let driver = CreateFirefoxDriverInstance(); 
let testURL: string = 'www.example.com'; 
function CheckAccessRights(role: string) {
  console.log("This user has " + role + " access rights"); 
}
async function OpenWebPage() {
  (await driver).navigate().to(testURL).catch(function () {
    console.log("Promise Rejected");
  });
}
async function EnterUsernamePassword(uname: string, pass: string) {
  //Set the password and username to test the app with
  let varUsername: string = uname;
  let varPassword: string = pass;
  (await driver).navigate().to(testURL).then(async function () {
    console.log("Promise Rejected");
  });
  //Select the Login field to input the username
 (await driver).sleep(2000)
 .then(async function () 
 {
  (await driver).findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[1]/div/div/span/div/input"))
  .then(async function(newlogin_field: WebElement)
  {
    console.log("Input password in password field");
    newlogin_field.sendKeys(varUsername).then(async function () {
      //Select the password field to input the password
      (await driver).findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div/div/span/div/input"))
      .then(async function( password_field: WebElement)
      {
        console.log("Input username in login field");
        password_field.sendKeys(varPassword).catch(function () {
          console.log("Promise Rejected");
        });
      });
    });
  });
 });

  
}
async function CheckLoginPage(titleBDD: string) {
  (await driver).sleep(5000)
 .then(async function () 
 {
  //Click on the login button
  (await driver).findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[4]/button/span")).click().then(async function () {
    /*wait for the dashboard page to load"*/
    (await driver).sleep(5000).then(async function () {
      /*locate the dashboard toolbar*/
      (await driver).findElement(By.css("#root > div > div.page-content > div.toolbar > h1")).then(function (dashboard:WebElement) { 
        console.log("found the dashboard toolbar after logging"); 
        /* Get the text within the dashboard toolbar*/
        dashboard.getText().then(function (text:string) {
          console.log(text)
          /* Check whether we successfully logged in by comparing the actual Dashboard toolbar text with the expected text*/
          assert.equal(text,titleBDD);
        })
      });
    });
  });
});
}
Given(/^user has "(.*)" access rights$/, CheckAccessRights);
When('User visits the XYZ website', OpenWebPage);
When(/^User inputs the username "(.*)" and password "(.*)"$/, EnterUsernamePassword);
Then(/^User should see the login page with the  title containing the word "(.*)"$/, CheckLoginPage);

This is my DriverInstance.ts file which builds a driver for either chrome or firefox:

    import { Builder, Capabilities, ThenableWebDriver } from 'selenium-webdriver';
import { Options, ServiceBuilder, setDefaultService } from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';
import { Options as FirefoxOptions } from 'selenium-webdriver/firefox';

export function CreateChromeDriverInstance(): ThenableWebDriver {
    console.log("Creating a new chrome driver instance"); 
    let chromeOptions = new Options; 
    // chromeOptions.addArguments('--enable-dev-shm-usage'); 
    let chromeDriver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('chrome')
        .usingServer("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub") 
        .setChromeOptions(chromeOptions)
        .withCapabilities(Capabilities.chrome())
        .build();
    return chromeDriver;
}
export function CreateFirefoxDriverInstance(): ThenableWebDriver {
    console.log("Creating a new firefox driver instance"); 
    let firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions;
    let firefoxDriver = new Builder()
        .forBrowser('firefox')
        .usingServer("http://localhost:4444/wd/hub") 
        .setFirefoxOptions(firefoxOptions)
        .withCapabilities(Capabilities.firefox())
        .build();
    return firefoxDriver;
}
```

Which test runner can I use to run this same test on both the selenium nodes that I have set up?

This is my docker-compose.yml file

```
version: "3"
services:

  hub:
    image: selenium/hub
    ports:
      - "${PORT_HUB}:4444"

    environment:
      GRID_MAX_SESSION: 16
      GRID_BROWSER_TIMEOUT: 3000
      GRID_TIMEOUT: 3000
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}

  chrome:
    image: ${IMAGE_CHROME}
    container_name: web-automation_chrome
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=4
      - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=4
      - ACTIVE_PORT=1111
      - BROWSER=chrome
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "${PORT_CHROME}:5900"
    links:
      - hub

  firefox:
    image: ${IMAGE_FIREFOX}
    container_name: web-automation_firefox
    depends_on:
      - hub
    environment:
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR=hub
      - HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT=4444
      - NODE_MAX_SESSION=4
      - NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=4
      - ACTIVE_PORT=2222
      - BROWSER=firefox
    volumes:
      - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    ports:
      - "${PORT_FIREFOX}:5900"
    links:
      - hub
```

The .env file

```
PORT_FIREFOX=9002
PORT_CHROME=9001
PORT_HUB=4444
NODE_ENV=test
IMAGE_CHROME=selenium/node-chrome-debug
IMAGE_FIREFOX=selenium/node-firefox-debug
```

I know my test in Login.step file isn't really written well, I am employing the "promise chain of doom" but I will improve it later. Right Now I just want to focus on my test framework. I'm quite new to.. well everything but the internet has helped me get this far. I've been stuck on this for a week and that's when I realised I probably need actual help though. Any input is greatly appreciated.